# Clean syntax for conditionally folding a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, conditional-statements, fold

I'm relatively new to haskell, but in my searching I couldn't find an easy way to conditionally fold a list. i.e. When an element satisfies a condition (like in `filter`) to fold that element by a function (like `foldr` and `foldl`).

My workaround was to write the following helper function, then apply `map` to change the resulting list of pairs as my situation required.

```
-- This function returns tuples containing the elements which 
--    satisfy `cond` folded right, adding 1 to the second value
-- in each pair. (`snd` pair starts at 0)
-- Condition takes a single value (similar to `filter`)
-- NOTE: list cannot end with token
foldrOn cond list = 
    if (length list) > 0 then 
        if cond (head list) then 
            do
                let tmp = foldrOn cond (tail list)
                (fst (head tmp), snd (head tmp) + 1) : (tail tmp) 
                      -- fold token into char after it 
        else
            (head list, 0) : (foldrOn cond (tail list)) 
                      -- don't fold token
    else
        [] -- base case len list = 0

foldlOn cond list = ...
```

For example, the use-case would be something along the lines of wanting to remove the zeros in the following lists but remember how many were removed between each value.

```
-- the second value in each resultant pair represents the number of 
-- zeroes preceding the corresponding first value in the original list.
foldrOn (== 0) [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] -- [(1,0),(1,5),(1,3)]
foldrOn (== 0) [1,0,0,12,0,13] -- [(1,0),(12,2),(13,1)]
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Additionally, can this be done more optimally?

Comment: Your `foldrOn` doesn't get a binary function argument, so it is not really a `fold`. Please show the desired output of your use case.

Comment: Could you please edit your question by including some examples of use and expected output? I tried executing `foldrOn (== 0)` with both of your example inputs, but I don't understand how the actual behaviour aligns with the stated purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've made changes which should make the question easier to understand & included some examples.

Comment: Taking a step back, aren't you really looking to do a run-length encoding?

Comment: you don't need that `do`. `do { let {a=b} ; c }` is entirely the same as `let {a=b} in do c` and `do c` is just `c` when `c` is just one expression.

Comment: I urge you to avoid using `head` and `tail` ... pretty much ever. I know this is Haskell, but it reads like Lisp. Calculating the `length` of a list and checking if it's zero is (virtually) never a good idea. Normally you want to either use a standard fold/traversal or *pattern match* on the list to both determine whether it's empty and, if it's not, deconstruct it into its head and tail. In almost all other cases, you should use `null` to check if a list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,

```
foldrOn :: Num t => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [(a, t)]
-- foldrOn (== 0) [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] -- [(1,0),(1,5),(1,3)]
foldrOn p xs  =  foldr g [] xs
  where
  g x []        = [(x,0)]
  g x ((y,n):r)
    | p x       = ((y,n+1):r)
  g x r         = ((x,0):r)
```

This is the simplest, though it is recursive, i.e. will force the whole list to the end before starting returning its result.

To make it maximally lazy we'd have to use a lazy left fold. The skipping over the `p`-satisfying elements is still a recursive step, but at least the process will pause between each such span.

Lazy left fold is usually implemented as a `foldr` with additional argument being passed left to right along the list:

```
foldlOn :: Num t => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [(a, t)]
-- foldlOn (== 0) [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] -- [(1,0),(1,5),(1,3)]
foldlOn p xs  =  foldr g z xs 0
  where
  g x r i | p x       =         r (i+1)
          | otherwise = (x,i) : r 0
  z    _i             =         []
```

Or you could combine `span`/`break` and `unfoldr` to do the same.

You might find a way to use `groupBy` with some post-processing step:

```
GHCi> groupBy (\a b -> (==0) b) [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1]]

GHCi> groupBy (const (==0)) [1,2,0,0,1,0,1]
[[1],[2,0,0],[1,0],[1]]
```

Finishing this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can always bring some builtin machinery. The `Data.List` library is quite powerful:

```
import Data.List(mapAccumL)
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)

foldrOn cond = catMaybes . snd . mapAccumL combine 0 where
  combine a el =
    if cond el then (a + 1, Nothing)
    else (0, Just (el, a))
```

---

#### What's going on

Essentially, `foldrOn cond` is a composition of the following functions:

- `mapAccumL combine 0` which advances along the list modifying each element by information about the number of recently skipped entities (starting the count at `0` and resetting it whenever we find something that doesn't match the `cond` predicate).
- `snd` which discards the final state from the `mapAccumL`'s result
- `catMaybes` which removes the `Maybe` layer and leaves only the "present" values.

Comment: nice. the meaning is much more immediately apparent this way. ---- suggested edit: *" `mapAccumL combine 0` which advances along the list ... recently skipped entities, [starting the count at 0]"*. (unfortunately "traverse" is a bit overloaded term, in Haskell)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by using pattern matching to make your own implementation more idiomatic, more obviously correct, and also (much) faster. We can also use *guards* in an idiomatic fashion rather than `if`/`then`/`else`; this is rather less important. There's also no reason to use `do` here, so we won't.

```hs
foldrOn _cond [] = []
foldrOn cond (hd : tl)
  | cond hd
  = case foldrOn cond tl of
      (x, y) : tl' -> (x, y + 1) : tl' 
                      -- fold token into char after it
      [] -> error "String ended on token."
  | otherwise
  = (hd, 0) : foldrOn cond tl
                      -- don't fold token
```

This is ... okay. But as Will Ness suggests, we don't actually gain anything by consing an "incomplete" element onto the result list. We can instead count up the `cond`-satisfying tokens until we reach the end of the block, and then produce a complete element. I think this makes the code a little easier to understand, and it should also run a little bit faster.

```
foldrOn cond = go 0
  where
    go count (hd : tl)
      | cond hd
      = go (count + 1) tl -- Don't produce anything; just bump the count
      | otherwise
      = (hd, count) : go 0 tl -- Produce the element and the count; reset the count to 0
    go count []
      | count == 0
      = []
      | otherwise
      = error "List ended on a token."
```

To *actually* run faster, you might need to tell the compiler explicitly that you really want to calculate the counts. You probably don't need to understand this part just yet, but it looks like this:

```
-- At the top of the file, add this line:
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

foldrOn cond = go 0
  where
    go !count (hd : tl)
      | cond hd
      = go (count + 1) tl -- Don't produce anything; just bump the count
      | otherwise
      = (hd, count) : go 0 tl -- Produce the element and the count; reset the count to 0
    go count []
      | count == 0
      = []
      | otherwise
      = error "List ended on a token."
```

This can be written as a fold in the manner Will Ness demonstrates.

Note: while it's possible to avoid the `BangPatterns` language extension, doing so is a bit annoying.

Comment: The “annoying” equivalent with `seq` instead of `BangPatterns` is actually pretty straightforward, codewise. `f !x = e` is equivalent to `f x = seq x e`, so this becomes ``go count (hd : tl) | cond hd = count `seq` go (count + 1) tl | otherwise = count `seq` ((hd, count) : go 0 tl)``. An explanation of `seq` is beyond this comment, but all it does is add an evaluation dependency: here, *if* the result is evaluated (which happens whenever the caller inspects the next constructor of the list using pattern matching) *then* the previous `count` value is also evaluated.

Comment: @JonPurdy, yes, I know. But having to say `seq` twice is annoying when I know that I probably only need it *once* when compiling with optimization. And it's so noisy in the code!

Comment: Of course, I figured you do know, my comment was for our dear readers :)

Comment: I edited to see the effect of it. had lengthy comment here that I later removed about how visual code structure should follow the inner code structure -- guards to the left, clauses code to the right of the equal sign.... but even adding just four spaces before each of the `=`s (and indenting their code accordingly) in your code as it is now, helps a lot with turning this linear "wall-of-code" appearance to the tree-like one, which, for me, improves the readability sharply. YMMV of course....